# Generating two standard normal variables with specific correlation (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, random, correlation

I want to generate two standard normal variables (mean = 0, variance = 0) with a specific correlation (e.g. .2). To do this I am using the mvnrnd() function. Documentation [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/mvnrnd.html)

I am having trouble understanding the documentation completely, but I believe this would do the trick: mvnrnd([0,0],[1,.2;.2,1])
with [0,0] representing the mean of the two variables and [1,.2;.2,1] representing the covariance matrix (which is the same as the correlation matrix since the variance for both variables is 1) that looks like this:

1 .2

.2 1

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. If you have doubts, calculate the correlation on the output and verify it is approximately 0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  If you want many (N) realizations, try:

```
a = mvnrnd(zeros(N,2), [1,.2;.2 1]);
```

or

```
a = mvnrnd([0 0], [1,.2;.2 1], N);
```